# node.js non blocking code example failure

Tags: javascript, node.js

Following this link http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2012/11/nodejs-itself-is-blocking-only-its-io-is-non-blocking/ I'm trying to code two non-blocking functions:

blocking code:

```
function LongBucle() {
    for (x=0;x<=10000;x++) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}

function ShortBucle() {
    for (x=0;x<=10;x++) {
        console.log("short "+x);
     }
}

LongBucle();
console.log("Long bucle end");

ShortBucle();
console.log("Short bucle end");
```

Now I try to turn the code into non blocking code so the 
"console.log("Short bucle end");" should be shown first?

```
function ShortBucle(callback) {
    for (x=0;x<=10;x++) {
        console.log("corto "+x);
    }
callback(x);
}


function LongBucle(callback) {
    for (x=0;x<=10000;x++) {
        console.log(x);
     }
     callback(x);
}


LongBucle(function(err) {
    console.log('Long bucle end');
});


ShortBucle(function(err) {
   console.log('short bucle end');
});
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calling callback is still blocking, use `setImmediate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a callback doesn't make your code asynchronous. As Javascript is a single-threaded language, only one instruction is executed at a given time. This means that this snippet will hang forever, no matter what you do:

```
function a() {
    while (true) {}
}

a();
console.log('Done.');
```

To process some amount of code *later* (ie. asynchronously), you can use [`process.nexTick()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) or [`setImmediate`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg):

```
function LongBucle(callback) {
    setImmediate(function() {
        for (x=0;x<=10000;x++) {
            console.log(x);
         }
         callback(x);
    })
}
```

[Here is an article](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick) explaining `process.nextTick()` and the event loop in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you setImmediate worked but then I should accept this webpage example is wrong? http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2012/11/nodejs-itself-is-blocking-only-its-io-is-non-blocking/

Comment: Which example are you talking about?